# First letter from an input.value doesn't get converted to an uppercase

Tags: javascript

I have 4 inputs which value gets grabbed when the addContact function gets called, before I send these values into the database I need to convert the first letter of the first name and the last name to an uppercase so that I can apply it to the HTML properly, but it's just not working. I have stepped over the code in the console and the code gets run, but the two values doesn't change. I've tried to change the whole thing to uppercase and lowercase as well but nothing seem to change the values when the code is run. I get no errors. What am I missing?

```
addContact: function() {

    var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;

    firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase();

    dbContactsRef.push({firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email, phoneNumber: phone});
},
```

Comment: `.toUpperCase()` returns a new string that is the value of the original string changed to upper case - it doesn't modify the original string. You probably want `firstName = firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstName.substr(1);`

Comment: You can also use `firstName = firstName.replace(/^./,function(c){return c.toUpperCase()})`.

Comment: @RobG is there any advantages of using that compared to the accepted answer?

Comment: No, it's just another way to do it. Same for nnnnnn's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable. You need:

```
firstName = firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstName.slice(1)
lastName = lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lastName.slice(1)
```

Comment: That worked, and I learned something new. Double win, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`toUpperCase()` method does not change the original string. It returns it.